# How can I make onboard PC speaker beep on Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 LTS?

Tags: command-line, server, 22.04

I have two old machines that I use as file servers. The first one has a [GIGABYTE GA-G41M-Combo (rev. 2.0)](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-G41M-Combo-rev-20#ov) with an [Intel Core 2 Duo Processor E7400 (3M Cache, 2.80 GHz, 1066 MHz FSB)](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/36500/intel-core2-duo-processor-e7400-3m-cache-2-80-ghz-1066-mhz-fsb.html) and the second one an [ASRock 4Core1600Twins-P35](https://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/4core1600twins-p35/index.asp#Manual) with an [Intel Core 2 Quad Processor Q9550 (12M Cache, 2.83 GHz, 1333 MHz FSB)](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/33924/intel-core2-quad-processor-q9550-12m-cache-2-83-ghz-1333-mhz-fsb.html). Both machines have **onboard audio** and **onboard PC speakers**, for sure!!! On both machines I have installed "[Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 LTS](https://ubuntu.com/download/server)" and "[CasaOS](https://casaos.io/)" and I am trying to create a service, or something like that, which will make beep sound using **onboard PC speaker** (*not onboard audio*), when CasaOS is loaded. But before I even get there, my problem is when I am testing the "beep" program. On both machines, I can't get the beep sound through the onboard PC speaker.

I installed "beep" by typing `sudo apt-get install beep` but when I type `beep` I get this message `beep: Error: Could not open any device`.

I have read some old similar articles and questions which mention some solutions like `sudo modprobe pcspkr`, or to comment the `blacklist pcspkr` line into `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file, but none of them helped me to solve this issue.

---

**EDIT**:

1. When I run `sudo modprobe pcspkr` it just waits for next input without any errors.
2. The output of running `lsmod | grep pcspkr` is `pcspkr 16384 0`.
3. The output of `sudo grep -R pcspkr /etc/modprobe.d/` is
   `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf:# blacklist pcspkr`.
4. The output of `paplay /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/bell.oga` is `Command 'paplay' not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install pulseaudio-utils`.
5. But I can take a simple beep sound when I run this `sudo sh -c "echo -e '\\a' > /dev/console"`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us: What happens when you run `sudo modprobe pcspkr`? Any errors? What is the output of running `lsmod | grep pcspkr` after running the `modprobe` command? What is the output of `sudo grep -R pcspkr /etc/modprobe.d/`? Also, does something like `paplay /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/bell.oga` produce a sound? If that file doesn't exist, try any other ogg file in the `/usr/share/sounds` folder.

Comment: @terdon I edited my question...

Comment: Well, you could install `paplay`, but I think that needs the whole audio system so is probably not what you want. Ans anyway, the really odd thing here is that you say that `sudo sh -c "echo -e '\\a' > /dev/console"` works! I suppose that just `echo -e '\a'` does not work, right? However, presumably you set up CasaOS as root right? Can't you use this approach to beep when it has loaded? What is the signal that tells you it has loaded?

Comment: Yes `echo -e '\a'` doesn't work. Yes I setup CasaOS as root. Hm, I don't want to use this approach because I don't want just a simple beep. I don't know what is the signal that tells me it has loaded because I haven't reached that point yet. :) I'm still experimenting with whether my computer can make sounds through the Beep... The most weird this is that yesterday where I was looking for a solution here and there, I run something that I don't remember and beep was working!!!

Comment: Try installing `paplay` then, and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After many hours of researching, I ended up with this solution...

1. Install "**beep**" by running `sudo apt-get install beep`.
2. Run `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` to edit `blacklist.conf` file which is located at `/etc/modprobe.d` folder and comment `blacklist snd_pcsp` and `blacklist pcspkr` lines so to remove them both from blacklist.

   ```
   # low-quality, just noise when being used for sound playback, causes
   # hangs at desktop session start (Ubuntu: #246969)
   # blacklist snd_pcsp

   # ugly and loud noise, getting on everyone's nerves; this should be done by a
   # nice pulseaudio bing (Ubuntu: #77010)
   # blacklist pcspkr
   ```
3. Run `sudo usermod -aG input $USER` so to add current user to the input group, which will give the necessary permissions to access the device.
4. Reboot.
5. To test just type `beep` into CLI and hit `enter`.

For more information on how to use `beep` please visit this [link](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/beep.1.html).

Comment: So after this setup, what is the command which makes a sound on the PC speaker?

Comment: Just type `beep` and hit enter. Another example `beep -f 3500 -l 250 -d 250 -r 3`. For more information take a look here https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/beep.1.html .